# Getting value of textarea which is under control of tinymce editor using jquery without sending form

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have some textarea

```
<textarea name='text' id='text' ></textarea>
```

which is under control of tinymce script.

And I have simple javascript

```
alert ($('#text').val());
```

which gives me nothing. Problem is that tinymce is converting textarea into something , so actually there is no textarea with id 'text' anymore. Because of that javascript gives empty alerts when I press submit button even if there is some text typed in textarea.

So question is how can javascript get the value of such textarea on the fly whenever I need it ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be possible using the [`get` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.get) and [`getContent` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent) methods:

```
var value = tinymce.get('text').getContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method of the TinyMCE instance that can "sync" the TinyMCE content (an IFRAME) with your textarea. I think the method is triggerSave(). Look also here: [Need to autosave TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953384/need-to-autosave-tinymce)