# Getting value from TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Im using TinyMCE editor in a page but i need to grab the value using JQuery.

I am totally lost on how to do this, i have tried using various id's and attempting to fetch the value but it just wont work with anything.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/37MN3/)

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    tinyMCE.init({
            // General options
           mode : "exact",
            elements : "thisID",

             // Skin options
            skin : "o2k7",
            skin_variant : "silver",    
    });

    derp();
});


    function derp() {
        $('#go').click( function() {
//             alert('derp');
          x = $('#thisID_ifr').val(); //this is where i attempt to get the value of the textarea but its not working?!?
            alert(x);
        });
        //
    }
```

Comment: Just managed to find the answer on this site, couldn't find it earlier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830541/getting-value-of-textarea-which-is-under-control-of-tinymce-editor-using-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to get value from the text area

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

// Get the raw contents from the editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});

//Get the text content from the editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'text'});

// Get content of a specific editor:
tinyMCE.get('thisID').getContent();
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/37MN3/1/)**